# 3D Text visible from all angles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a soccer stadium, and I want to write the stadium name on the entrance of the stadium. But, when I'm in the stadium, or somewhere else, I also see the text. From all angles.

I know the help pages of Unity about 3D text and I read a lot of questions and answers about this problem. But I just can't fix it.

I tried to add a shader to a material, and I added the material to the 3D text, but then I can't add a font texture. I have the Arial font in my assets folder, but when I press 'select font texture', this font isn't in the options I can choose.

Isn't there another option to write text on a wall, on a way you only can see it from the front?

So, on the second picture I should't see the text:

[image: Front]

[image: Another angle]

Please don't think I'm lazy and I didn't Google, because I have searched for hours. But I really don't get it, it's probably something really stupid but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner with Unity, especially with shaders and importing/adding fonts.

Comment: Without seeing the shader, it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: Have you tried http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=3DText ?:-)

Comment: @Tom I'm pretty sure that's what he's using.

Comment: @Draco18s Just clarifying.

Comment: Using a GameObject > 3D Object > 3D Text should do it so the problem might come from your stadium, not from the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126, its free and it will give the text in a form of mesh, so it will be just like any other gameobject, you can interact with it, use physics on it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible solutions, but the main ones are these:

---

### You set the `Canvas` for that text to world-space.

To implement this solution, you can follow the [official tutorial on the subject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html).

---

### You can use a text-to-mesh conversion plugin.

There are many to choose from, but one that was officially acquired by Unity and  is used by most indie developers when they need such functionality is [Text Mesh Pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126).